# How can i protect api from client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

I'm developing a site with react and nextjs. So in the API folder, I write some API endpoints. Now I don't know how can I protect them from clients?
I want to use these APIs directly from the site. and I won't the user be able to access API from his browser.
With jwt can I solve this problem? Or right solution is something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your own API endpoints, it should be running on its own server, e.g. Express.js.

If it's a 3rd-party API, you could add private information like password, API keys, etc, onto a .env file. You don't need to hide the API endpoints themselves in this case as they will be visible to the client anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if your client never triggers a request to your server then your API should not be visible, but also you can add some pretty basic validation in the case that someone reaches your API, like read a specific token in your API that only your server knows or something like that.

Comment: Yeap, I like this solution. Do you mean jwt? Or even OAuth2?